# How to move a view onto another view with animation

Tags: android, animation, view, move, transfer

I want to make a button which will move onto a specific view when pressed and will come back when pressed again. How can i achieve this? Is there any library or sample code?

Comment: On which view you want to move your button ?

Comment: for example on an empty textview

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectAnimator for achieving this, to animate a view to your desired directions.  There is also a simplified library

https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations

Let me Know if it helps you.

Comment: let me know if this helped you. ;)